# Sort a String array by second word

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have the following data

```
1. John Smith
2. Tom Cruise
3. Chuck Norris
4. Bill Gates
5. Steve Jobs
```

As you can see, the data is in specific format, `[ID]. [Firstname] [Lastname]`. Is there a way to sort this array by `Firstname`?

Output should look something like this:

```
4. Bill Gates
3. Chuck Norris
1. John Smith
5. Steve Jobs
2. Tom Cruise
```

Comment: _" Is there a way to sort this array by firstname?"_ - Yes, you use a custom `Comparator` class.  What have you done so far?

Comment: nothing because I'm not that of a pro to even get started with, its not very nice to leave downvotes even though i've well structured my question with formats and the question itself was very simple.

Comment: If you visit the [help] and read [ask] you will learn the rules by which questions are evaluated here.  Wishing for it to work differently does not make it so.

Comment: @JimGarrison I've already paid a visit to that page prior to posting this, everything is posted by the rules and is in neat structure, format, simplicity, input & ouput. stop being abusive to the community and downvoting for joy

Comment: You show no effort. Your question is "Here's a problem. Write the code for me". That is off-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use lambda to pass your own comparison criteria.

```
String[] names = {"1. John Smith", "2. Tom Cruise", "3. Chuck Norris", "4. Bill Gates", "5. Steve Jobs"};

ArrayList<String> namesList = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0; i<names.length; i++) {
    namesList.add(names[i]);
}

Collections.sort(namesList, (name1, name2) -> name1.split(" ")[1].compareTo(name2.split(" ")[1]));

for(String name : namesList) {
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

Output:

```
4. Bill Gates
3. Chuck Norris
1. John Smith
5. Steve Jobs
2. Tom Cruise
```

Answer (score 1):

You can provide your custom comparator to sort by first name

```
    List<String> data = Arrays.asList("1. John Smith", "2. Tom Cruise", "3. Chuck Norris", "4. Bill Gates", "5. Steve Jobs");
    Comparator<String> c = (s1, s2) -> s1.split("\\s+")[1].compareTo(s2.split("\\s+")[1]);
    List<String> sorted = data.stream().sorted(c).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(sorted);
```

output

```
[4. Bill Gates, 3. Chuck Norris, 1. John Smith, 5. Steve Jobs, 2. Tom Cruise]
```

or simply

```
    Comparator<String> com = Comparator.comparing(s -> s.split("\\s+")[1]);

    Comparator<String> old = new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
            return s1.split("\\s+")[1].compareTo(s2.split("\\s+")[1]);
        }
    };
```

by passing to Collections

```
Collections.sort(data, old);
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need a custom comparator

```
String[] names = new String[]{"1. John Smith","2. Tom Cruise","3. Chuck Norris","4. Bill Gates","5. Steve Jobs"};
List<String> nameList = Arrays.asList(names);
Collections.sort(nameList, new Comparator<String>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(String arg0, String arg1) {
        String firstName0 = arg0.split(". ")[1].split(" ")[0];
        String firstName1 = arg1.split(". ")[1].split(" ")[0];
        return firstName0.compareTo(firstName1);
    }
});
```

Prints :

```
[4. Bill Gates, 3. Chuck Norris, 1. John Smith, 5. Steve Jobs, 2. Tom Cruise]
```